# Sharepoint 2013 workflow Email

Tags: workflow

Sharepoint 2013 Server EE
SharePoint Designer 2013

I have a list item that has a field "POC". This is a multi-select field.

It is a lookup from the contacts list.

On demand, the user wants to see ALL POCs contact data for that item.

I thought of sending an email through a workflow but all the Names, emails, etc. get grouped together.... Example; **Name:** Smith, Jones, Doe **Email:** smith@aaa.com, Jones@aaa.com, Doe@aaa.com.

Anyone know a way to produce a cleaner view in a workflow email OR another way to achieve this request?

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see it as such is because of the way the Multi-Choice Lookup column stores data internally. One alternative would to pass the actual string through a String split routine and store it in a variable (the new Collection type - Dictionary - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554504.aspx in SharePoint 2013). Afterwards is up to you what to do with it.